# Infix to Postfix conversion in Java using Stack and Queue ADTS

Tags: java, data-structures

working on code for converting an infix expression to postfix expression using Linked list stack and queue ADT's. We cannot use javas build in classes. I'm having difficulty reaching the correct answer but currently my code compiles and shows no errors which has made the debugging process difficult for me. This is what the output shows
[Output i'm experiencing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFapO.png)

I did some research and I from what i'm seeing I need to create a loop through the the postfix expression from 0 to n-1 and dequeue every item in the postfix queue and cast as (char). I'm not sure how to do this correct or if this is actually the answer to my issue.

If anyone can help that would be most appreciated. Here is my code

```
public class InfixToPostfixConversion
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        InfixToPostfix evaluation = new InfixToPostfix();
        
        String exp = "A+B*(C^D-E)";
        System.out.println("Infix Expression: " + exp);
        System.out.println("Postfix Expression: " + evaluation);
    }
}
class LLStackADT 
{
    private Node top;
    private int size;

    public LLStackADT () {
        top = null;
        size = 0;
    }          

    public boolean empty () {
        return (top == null);
    }

    public void push (char number) {
        Node newNode = new Node ();
        newNode.setData(number);
        newNode.setNext(top);
        top = newNode;
        size++;     
    }

    public char pop () {
        char i;
        i = top.getData();
        top = top.getNext();
        size--;
        return i;
    }

    public char ontop () {
        char i = pop();
        push(i);
        return i;
    }

    public int size () {
        return size;
    }

}

class LLQueueADT 
{
    private int size;
    private Node front;
    private Node rear;

    public LLQueueADT () {
        size = 0;
        front = null;
        rear = null;
    }

    public boolean empty () {
        return (size == 0);
    }

    public void enqueue (char number) {
        Node newNode = new Node ();
        newNode.setData(number);
        newNode.setNext(null);
        if (this.empty()) 
            front = newNode;
        else
            rear.setNext(newNode);
        rear = newNode;
        size++;
    }

    public int dequeue () {
        int i;
        i = front.getData();
        front = front.getNext();
        size--;
        if (this.empty())
            rear = null;
        return i;
    }

    public int front () {
        return front.getData();
    }

    public int size () {
        return size;
    }
}

class InfixToPostfix
{
    public static char precedence(char c)
    {
        switch (c){
            case '+':
            case '-':
            return 1;
            case '*':
            case '/':
            return 2;
            case '^':
            return 3;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static String infixToPostFix(String expression)
    {
        String result = "";
        //Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        LLStackADT stack = new LLStackADT();
        for (char i = 0; i <expression.length() ; i++) 
        {
            char c = expression.charAt(i);
            //check if char is operator
            if(precedence(c) > 0)
            {
                while(stack.empty() == false && precedence(stack.ontop()) >= precedence(c))
                {
                    result += stack.pop();
                }
                stack.push(c);
            }else if(c == ')')
            {
                char x = stack.pop();
                while(x != '(')
                {
                    result += x;
                    x = stack.pop();
                }
            }
            else if(c == '(')
            {
                stack.push(c);
            }
            else
            {
                //character is neither operator nor ( 
                result += c;
            }
        }
        for (char i = 0; i <= stack.size(); i++) 
        {
            result += stack.pop();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class Node 
{

    private char data;
    private Node next;

    public Node () 
    {
        //this(0, null);
        return;
    }

    public Node (char d) 
    {
        data = d;
    }

    public Node (char d, Node n) 
    {
        data = d;
        next = n;
    }

    public void setData (char newData)
    {
        data = newData;
    }

    public void setNext (Node newNext)
    {
        next = newNext;
    } 

    public char getData () 
    {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getNext () 
    {
        return next;
    }

    public void displayNode () 
    {
        System.out.print (data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When initialising the `InfixToPostfix` function, you need to call the function `infixToPostFix` to convert the string to a postfix notation. Currently, in the program, there are no functions called to convert the expression into postfix notation.

```
InfixToPostfix evaluation = new InfixToPostfix();
String exp = "A+B*(C^D-E)";
String evaluated = evaluation.infixToPostFix(exp);
System.out.println("Postfix Expression: " + evaluated);
```

[image: This is the screenshot of output when the code snippet is added to the program. Your functions are correct.]